# Imshow and pcolor throw errors when trying to create test pattern-style bars

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create an image to use as a test pattern for a new colormap I'm creating.  The map is supposed to have nine unique colors with breaks at the integers from 0-8.  The colormap itself is fine, but I can't seem to generate the image itsel.

I'm using pandas to make the test array like this:

```
mask=pan.DataFrame(index=np.arange(0,100),columns=np.arange(1,91))

mask.ix[:,1:10]=0.0
mask.ix[:,11:20]=1.0
mask.ix[:,21:30]=2.0
mask.ix[:,31:40]=3.0
mask.ix[:,41:50]=4.0
mask.ix[:,51:60]=5.0
mask.ix[:,61:70]=6.0
mask.ix[:,71:80]=7.0
mask.ix[:,81:90]=8.0
```

Maybe not the most elegant method, but it creates the array I want.

However, when I try to plot it using either imshow or pcolor I get an error.  So:

```
fig=plt.figure() 
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)     
image=ax.imshow(mask)
fig.canvas.draw()
```

yields the error: "TypeError: Image data can not convert to float"

and substituting pcolor for imshow yields this error: "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'view'"

However, when I replace he values in mask with anything else - say random numbers - it plots just fine:

```
mask=pan.DataFrame(values=rand(100,90),index=np.arange(0,100),columns=np.arange(1,91))
fig=plt.figure() 
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)     
image=ax.imshow(mask)
fig.canvas.draw()
```

yields the standard colored speckle one would expect (no errors).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your dataframe is full of objects, not numbers. You can see it if you do `mask.dtypes`. If you want to use `pandas` dataframes, create `mask` by specifying the data type:

```
mask=pan.DataFrame(index=np.arange(0,100),columns=np.arange(1,91), dtype='float')
```

otherwise `pandas` cannot know which data type you want. After that change your code should work.

However, if you want to just test the color maps with integers, then you might be better off using simple `numpy` arrays:

```
mask = np.empty((100,90), dtype='int')

mask[:, :10] = 0
mask[:, 10:20] = 1
...
```

And, of course, there are shorter ways to do that filling, as well. For example:

```
mask[:] = np.arange(90)[None,:] / 10
```